# Create a list of the files on a hard drive and name the list using the volume name

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

So, I know this creates a list of the files in the drive:

```
SET /P drive=Enter drive letter: 
tree %drive%: /a > "C:\Drivelists\%listname%.txt"
```

but I don't know how to get the drive's name automatically to replace that listname. I know that this one at least gives me the name:

```
wmic logicaldisk where name="%drive%:" get volumename
```

But I don't know if I even can somehow get it from there or if there's a better way. I'm guessing it's rather easy task but I just don't know the key element here. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I set a variable to a drive volume name?

The following batch file shows how to do this using a `for /f` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p _drive=Enter drive letter:
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk where name^="%_drive%:" get volumename`) do (
  set _volume=%%i
  goto :done
  )
:done
@echo %_volume%
tree %_drive%: /a > "C:\Drivelists\%_volume%.txt"
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `skip=1` is used to skip the `wmic` header line.
- `goto :done` is use to skip the `wmic` extra blank line.
- `C:\Drivelists\` must already exist.
- Not all drives have volume names.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [tree](http://ss64.com/nt/tree.html) - Display the folder structure of a drive or path as a graphical tree.Display the folder structure of a drive or path as a graphical tree.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. I do name all my volumes for easier use. And thanks for those links too, they ought to be helpful in the future.